# Manage Fragment BackStack Programatically in Navigation Components

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I am working on a Project that uses **Single Activity** **Multiple Fragments**. I am using `Jetpack Navigation Components`. I am able to navigate using `NavGraph, NavHost and NavController` but the problem is, `there are multiple situations where I need to move from one fragment to other fragment and vice-versa and require to clear the backstack accordingly`.`I was managing these using actions in NavGraph` **Example- Such as moving to Dashboard Fragment from SignIn Fragment on successful authentication where SigIn Fragment is removed from the backstack. Another example- Moving to ForgotPassword Fragment from SignIn Fragment in case having trouble with password, again clearing the exisiting fragment from backstack and more such cases**.`All the mentioned examples required to generate multiple actions from one fragment to other and vice-versa`. Managing this with `individual actions` in `NavGraph` makes the `Navgraph and Fragments look messed up with multiple actions`. It want to do it programatically in `class files`. **How to implement it??**

**Note**- `I know that Navigation components uses the existing FragmentManager and FragmentTransactions`. And I am asking for any class or api from `Navigation Components` so that the `backstack` can be managed easily without using `FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction`.

**Note:-** **I know I can navigate from one fragment to another in class files/programmatically without using NavGraph by using** `view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.Nextfragment)` but this doesn't help to manage the `backstack`

Comment: There are two possible solutions to clean it up for you, 1st make nested nav graphs, like 1 graph as login_nav_graph and another one as home_nav_graph, and include both of them in the main_nav_graph to keep it clean. Secondly, you can do is make two activities with separate nav graphs to keep the graphs clean.

Comment: It's not about using nested graphs or multiple activities. I want to do it programmatically. There must be some way.

Comment: what is it that you are looking for ?

Comment: I already answered my question. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Okay, so this is how it worked..**

There's already a method available in two `overloaded forms`, in `NavController class` called `popBackStack() that pops the current Fragment(if available) from the backstack` and `popBackStack(@IdRes int destinationId, boolean inclusive) which takes user specified destination(next_fragment_id) and a boolean which is used as flag for popToInclusive`

**What I did**-

```
binding.tvMoveToSignUp.setOnClickListener {
            it.findNavController().apply {
                popBackStack(R.id.signInFragment, true)
                navigate(R.id.signUpFragment)
            }
        }
```

***In my case above,*** `I'am first getting the NavController by calling view.findNavController() then popping the current fragment by calling popBackStack(R.id.signInFragment, true) which is` **SignInFragment** and setting `flag popToInclusive to true to pop upto SignInFragment` and `then navigating to` **SignUpFragment** by `calling navigate(R.id.signUpFragment)`

Comment: Technically you're writing more number of lines which is the opposite of making it simple and straightforward in xml.

Comment: Since the ```popBackStack()``` method only extra thing here. How does 1 extra line of code makes my code lengthy and not simpler??

Comment: In order to access the method, you added 4 additional lines

Comment: In my case, this solution helped me. Fits for my app. Thanks @DebarshiBhattacharjee

Answer (score 2):

it is very simple,go to your **nav_graph.xml** file and then goto your **action tag** , write **popUpToInclusive="true"** , then write **popUpTo="@id/splashScreen"** ( here pass the id of that screen , which you want to remove , in my case it was splashScreen). check the below code for better understanding..

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/splashScreen"
        android:name="com.codingwithjks.firebase.SplashScreen"
        android:label="splash_screen"
        tools:layout="@layout/splash_screen" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_splashScreen_to_showUploads"
            app:destination="@id/showUploads"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"
            app:popUpTo="@id/splashScreen"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim" />
    </fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of using `Jetpack Navigation Components` is you **do not need to take care of backstack**. Just like in old days with FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction.

> I am asking for any class or api from Navigation Components so that
> the backstack can be managed easily without using FragmentManager and
> FragmentTransaction

**This statement has contradiction.**

Navigation component provide you mechanism of moving between `n` number of fragments, with all option you have mentioned like(Navigate using ID, using Safe Args Action, using NavController.popBackStack(), NavController.navigateUp() other).

> Example 1- Such as moving to Dashboard Fragment from SignIn Fragment
> on successful authentication where SigIn Fragment is removed from the
> backstack.

> Example 2- Moving to ForgotPassword Fragment from SignIn Fragment in
> case having trouble with password, again clearing the exiting
> fragment from backstack and more such cases

From both of your example it seems like you do have a complicate structure but you are trying to put each fragment in a single NavGraph.

Instead of poppingUP multiple times you can create NestedGraphs with similar flow of fragment. So when you will move to Dashboard Fragment NevGraph, from Login Flow graph.

Please go through [Design navigation graphs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph) to take understanding when there is a need for Nested Graph.

```
binding.tvMoveToSignUp.setOnClickListener {
            it.findNavController().apply {
                popBackStack(R.id.signInFragment, true)
                navigate(R.id.signUpFragment)
            }
        }
```

What you did here is correct in your way, but I am sure this will not be the best design pattern. Think of any *Bank Application* and test your use cases with it.
From developer perspective as well, I am not going to remember all the fragment I would have `popUp()` to or fragment which I have open as `inclusive` when I might have more than 100 fragments.

Here is another good article on [NestedGraphs](https://proandroiddev.com/handle-complex-navigation-flow-with-single-activity-and-android-jetpacks-navigation-component-6ad988602902). I hop you get the point I'm trying to established.

Happy Coding !!

Comment: ```Nested NavGraph for Fragments for simple use case like mine``` will complicate it further. No issues. Happy Coding !!

Comment: well... [Ian Lake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake) and other don't think the same in [google I/O 2019](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FJFGq0asqSuA%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DJFGq0asqSuA&tbnid=_E-4JoLto9RkUM&vet=12ahUKEwi1wOuL0JPrAhVHYSsKHYCEDTIQMygIegUIARCiAQ..i&docid=YqZSwVJgEgJxBM&w=1280&h=720&q=ian%20lake%20google&safe=off&ved=2ahUKEwi1wOuL0JPrAhVHYSsKHYCEDTIQMygIegUIARCiAQ) :)

Comment: but I agreed, your way is also another way of keeping things... intact.